# On error Console.WriteLine C# HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am new to C# and find it difficult to output the result of a search with HtmlAgilityPack.

I would like to show "`Not found`" when the requested search cannot be found.

The thing is, I cannot figure out how to do so. Currently if I enter a non-existing search phrase, the application just exits.

How can this be resolved?

Here is my code:

```
string exampleurl = "https://example.com";

Console.WriteLine("Checking for text");
htmlDocument = web.Load(exampleurl);
var scanfortext = htmlDocument
                        .DocumentNode
                        .SelectSingleNode("//*[text()[contains(., 'Test123')]]")
                        .InnerText;

Console.WriteLine(scanfortext);
```

Comment: use try/catch https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

As by [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode?view=net-6.0) the return value of `SelectSingleNode` is `null` when it cannot find the search pattern.

> Returns:
> The first XmlNode that matches the XPath query or null if no matching node is found.

Since you use the inner html, this will result in a `NullReferenceException`. Meaning; your trying to access a un-(or null) initialized value.  Change your code to use the [conditional operator `?`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator), which checkes for `null` and it will work.

```
string scanfortext = htmlDocument.DocumentNode
              .SelectSingleNode("//*[text()[contains(., 'Test123')]]")?
              .InnerText;

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(scanfortext))
    Console.WriteLine("No results");
else
    Console.WriteLine(scanfortext);
```

Note that the `?` operator is only a replacement for an if statement with a null check.

This part troubles me though:

> Currently if I enter a non-existing search phrase, the application just exits.

It looks like you're not using the debugger to analyse your problem but just run the executable. Using a debugger will very much increase your understanding of the workings of your program - and if such an error arises: it tells you very clearly what it is and where it occurs.

Some common debuggers:

- Visual Studio Community
- Visual Studio Code
- Rider